# Exlude MQL4 colors from formating (e.g. C'250,250,250')

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, metatrader4

I'm using visual studio code for MQL4 files (*.mq4 - Metatrader) and using cpp associations in my settings

```
 "files.associations": {
      "*.mqh": "cpp",
      "*.mq4": "cpp",
      "*.mq5": "cpp",
   }
```

I also switched to the Google formatter with the following setting

```
"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BasedOnStyle: Google, IndentWidth: 4, ColumnLimit: 0}"
```

Everything is perfect but in mq4 you can use predefined colors like clrBlack, clrWhite, .... or use any RGB value in the format

```
C'250,250,250'
```

When I use such a RGB color and format the file the formatter adds a space after the C - so C'250,250,250' gets

```
C '250,250,250' <-- see the space after "C"
```

and this doesn't compile anymore.

How can I "whitelist" this for the cpp formatter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The C++ extension uses clang-format to format the code.  You would need to create a feature request for the LLVM folks to implement it.  The C++ extension doesn't own this component.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the method:

```
StringToColor("33,44,33")
```